# Is there a quick way to recognize HTML ASCII codes in a String or TextView?

Tags: java, android, regex, string, ascii

Here are some HTML ASCII Codes:

http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm

I have a string that may look like `"All in a hard day &#39;s work"`

What is the best way to replace that ascii code, with an apostrophe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Html.fromHtml(String)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml%28java.lang.String%29) to decode the string.

Comment: It probably would. Question is if that would be a problem.

Comment: Hm. I just deleted my answer in favor of yours. As it turns out, parsing HTML in Android is not as easy as I thought (since it depends on external libraries, for all I've read). This approach seems easier to handle anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Use Apache's `StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml(String)` or `StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml(String)`. This is found in the commons libraries.

If you need to preserve any HTML Markup, but just remove any ascii encoding, then you will have to construct a Map of the values you want to escape. It's an exercise in `String` manipulation, so it may be considered an 'ugly hack', but it will run quickly.

For example with some pseudo code,
Create a `Map<String, String>()`, and populate it with the the value you want to replace as the Key, and the value to replace it with in the Value.
Find the HTML ascii code in the document using a regular expression,
look the ascii code up in your `Map` of replacements
Replace the occurrence of the HTML ascii code with the text equivalent.

I will post some code over the weekend if I get a chance.

Comment: 1. Download commons-lang3 and then 2. String s = StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml4(String);