# Converting HTML ASCII codes to their character counterpart

Tags: java, android, html, ascii, utf

I am trying to convert HTML ASCII codes to legible characters. For example, I have HTML code which looks like this:

```
PING OK &#45; Packet loss &#61; 0&#37;&#44; RTA &#61; 2&#46;42 ms&nbsp;
```

And I would like to output it like this:

```
PING OK - Packet loss = 0%, RTA = 2.42 ms
```

However, Java / Android does not seem to support an easy way of doing this, or am I missing something? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this let me know

[Is there a quick way to recognize HTML ASCII codes in a String or TextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4228802/is-there-a-quick-way-to-recognize-html-ascii-codes-in-a-string-or-textview)

Answer (score 2):

Use Apache Commons [`StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml()`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeHtml%28java.lang.String%29).