# How do I identify HTML tags and replace a character in between?

Tags: java, html, regex

I have this string:

```
String s="<div style='font: 12px arial, sans-serif;'><b>Menu:<<>></b></div>"
```

I want to change the `<<>>` to `&amp;lt;&amp;lt;&amp;gt;&amp;gt;` to get the output:

```
String s="<div style='font: 12px arial, sans-serif;'><b>Menu:&amp;lt;&amp;lt;&amp;gt;&amp;gt;</b></div>"
```

I have used regex once a while back to retrieve text from the tags but how is this possible? I need the correct output.

I aim for this to be for general-purpose HTML tags, not just the particular ones in this post.

Comment: This looks like a job for [using regex to parse html!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Java .. i have rectified the post .. its just to give an idea not the actual code ..

Comment: Why do you want to turn `<<>>` into `&amp;lt;&amp;lt;&amp;gt;&amp;gt;` (which would actually render as `&lt;&lt;`) rather than `&lt;&lt;&gt;&gt;`?!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder its a requirement for other modules ..

Comment: @Rafay: I'd question it, it doesn't seem to make any sense. You'll end up with HTML that shows the character entities, rather than characters: http://jsbin.com/vabede/1

Comment: @T.J.Crowder it may be because parser they are using doesnt convert <<>> and treat it as a html tag

Comment: @Rafay: That would argue for `&lt;&lt;&gt;&gt;` (the accurate representation of those characters), not the other. (And `<<>>` *shouldn't* be parsed as an HTML tag; it isn't one.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use commons-lang's StringEscapeUtils class to do this.

```
string s="<div style='font: 12px arial, sans-serif;'><b>Menu:<<>></b></div>";    
System.out.println(StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml(s));
```

PS: your questions like this:[Is there a quick way to recognize HTML ASCII codes in a String or TextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4228802/is-there-a-quick-way-to-recognize-html-ascii-codes-in-a-string-or-textview)