# Why can't I replace "&#39;" to single quote

Tags: android

Why can't I replace " & # 3 9 ; " to single quote , I wrote this code but doesn't work.

*Code*

```
String originalText = "don&#39;t";
originalText = originalText.replace("&#39;", "\'");
```

The result is showing `dont` but I want it to be `don't`

> I set spaces between & # 3 9 ; because if I remove it will hide.

Comment: Why do you have to replace when you can directly use `\'`? Moreover, use this `&#39;` in xml not in java..

Comment: @sanjeev There is API put &#39; rather than single quote

Comment: @sanjeev Yes I use youtube captions using XML and It's put &#39; rather than single quote

Comment: I ran your code and its working fine for me , I got `don't` as output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you have trouble converting the HTML ASCII's it's advisable to use,

`Html.fromHtml("Don&#39;t");`

**Source:**

1. [Is there a quick way to recognize HTML ASCII codes in a String or TextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4228802/is-there-a-quick-way-to-recognize-html-ascii-codes-in-a-string-or-textview)
2. [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml(java.lang.String,%20int,%20android.text.Html.ImageGetter,%20android.text.Html.TagHandler))